# Stacked Bar Chart: By Type and Quantity

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

With Dc.Js and crossfilter, I want to create a Stacked bar chart.

Basicaly, I have two variables:

**type** : 2018, Never Covered, Other Periods

**district** : Thu Duc, etc....

In my StackedBarChart, I want to see for each district the quantity of .

Ive tried using this code:

```js
var paymentsRecord = [{
    date: "2011-11-14T16:17:54Z",
    quantity: 2,
    total: 190,
    tip: 100,
    type: "tab"
  },
  {
    date: "2011-11-14T16:20:19Z",
    quantity: 2,
    total: 190,
    tip: 100,
    type: "tab"
  },
  {
    date: "2011-11-14T16:28:54Z",
    quantity: 1,
    total: 300,
    tip: 200,
    type: "visa"
  },
  {
    date: "2011-11-14T16:30:43Z",
    quantity: 2,
    total: 90,
    tip: 0,
    type: "tab"
  },
  {
    date: "2011-11-14T16:48:46Z",
    quantity: 2,
    total: 90,
    tip: 0,
    type: "tab"
  },
  {
    date: "2011-11-14T16:53:41Z",
    quantity: 3,
    total: 90,
    tip: 0,
    type: "tab"
  },
  {
    date: "2011-11-14T16:54:06Z",
    quantity: 1,
    total: 100,
    tip: 0,
    type: "cash"
  },
  {
    date: "2011-11-14T16:58:03Z",
    quantity: 2,
    total: 90,
    tip: 0,
    type: "tab"
  },
  {
    date: "2011-11-14T17:07:21Z",
    quantity: 2,
    total: 90,
    tip: 0,
    type: "tab"
  },
  {
    date: "2011-11-14T17:22:59Z",
    quantity: 2,
    total: 90,
    tip: 0,
    type: "tab"
  },
  {
    date: "2011-11-14T17:25:45Z",
    quantity: 2,
    total: 200,
    tip: 0,
    type: "cash"
  },
  {
    date: "2011-11-14T17:29:52Z",
    quantity: 1,
    total: 200,
    tip: 100,
    type: "visa"
  }
];

var facts = crossfilter(paymentsRecord);
var dimensionByType = facts.dimension(function(d) {
  return d.type;
});
var groupByType = dimensionByType.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);


function reduceAdd(p, v) {
  p[v.quantity] = (p[v.quantity] || 0) + v.total;
  return p;
}

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
  p[v.quantity] = (p[v.quantity] || 0) - v.total;
  return p;
}

function reduceInitial() {
  return {};
}

var barChart = dc.barChart("#stackedBarChart")
  .width(1024)
  .height(200)
  .dimension(dimensionByType)
  .group(groupByType, "Quantity: 1", function(d) {
    return d.value[1] || 0;
  })
  .stack(groupByType, "Quantity: 2", function(d) {
    return d.value[2];
  })
  .stack(groupByType, "Quantity: 3", function(d) {
    return d.value[3];
  })
  .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(['tab', 'visa', 'cash']))
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
  .legend(dc.legend().x(500).y(1).itemHeight(15).gap(5));
barChart.yAxis().ticks(5);
barChart.xAxis().ticks(4);


dc.renderAll();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.9/dc.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.9/dc.min.css" />
<h1>StackedBart Chart:By Type and Quantity</h1>
<div id="stackedBarChart"></div>
```

To adapt for my needs into this one:

```js
var universe = [{
    "KMIST_TEMP_ID": "KTMPVN12119",
    "ID POP": "",
    "type": 2018,
    "pop": "No",
    "name": "Nha Thuoc An Binh",
    "Country": "",
    "Province": "Ho Chi Minh Province",
    "City": "Ho Chi Minh",
    "district": "Thu Duc",
    "ward": "Linh Trung",
    "name_full": "Ho Chi Minh ,Nha Thuoc An Binh ,Thu Duc, Linh Trung",
    "latitude": 10.8539167,
    "longitude": 106.7716921,
    "geo": "106.7716921,10.8539167",
    "amenity": "pharmacy",
    "date_entered": "2015-10-30T00:00:00",
    "date_issued": "2015-10-30T00:00:00"
  },

  {
    "KMIST_TEMP_ID": "KTMPVN12119",
    "ID POP": "",
    "type": 2018,
    "pop": "No",
    "name": "Nha Thuoc An Binh",
    "Country": "",
    "Province": "Ho Chi Minh Province",
    "City": "Ho Chi Minh",
    "district": "first",
    "ward": "Linh Trung",
    "name_full": "Ho Chi Minh ,Nha Thuoc An Binh ,Thu Duc, Linh Trung",
    "latitude": 10.8539167,
    "longitude": 106.7716921,
    "geo": "106.7716921,10.8539167",
    "amenity": "pharmacy",
    "date_entered": "2015-10-30T00:00:00",
    "date_issued": "2015-10-30T00:00:00"
  },

  {
    "KMIST_TEMP_ID": "KTMPVN12119",
    "ID POP": "",
    "type": "Never Covered",
    "pop": "No",
    "name": "Nha Thuoc An Binh",
    "Country": "",
    "Province": "Ho Chi Minh Province",
    "City": "Ho Chi Minh",
    "district": "new",
    "ward": "Linh Trung",
    "name_full": "Ho Chi Minh ,Nha Thuoc An Binh ,Thu Duc, Linh Trung",
    "latitude": 10.8539167,
    "longitude": 106.7716921,
    "geo": "106.7716921,10.8539167",
    "amenity": "pharmacy",
    "date_entered": "2015-10-30T00:00:00",
    "date_issued": "2015-10-30T00:00:00"
  },

  {
    "KMIST_TEMP_ID": "KTMPVN12119",
    "ID POP": "",
    "type": "Other Periods",
    "pop": "No",
    "name": "Nha Thuoc An Binh",
    "Country": "",
    "Province": "Ho Chi Minh Province",
    "City": "Ho Chi Minh",
    "district": "Thu Duc",
    "ward": "Linh Trung",
    "name_full": "Ho Chi Minh ,Nha Thuoc An Binh ,Thu Duc, Linh Trung",
    "latitude": 10.8539167,
    "longitude": 106.7716921,
    "geo": "106.7716921,10.8539167",
    "amenity": "pharmacy",
    "date_entered": "2015-10-30T00:00:00",
    "date_issued": "2015-10-30T00:00:00"
  }
];



var xdata = crossfilter(universe);
var dimensionByType = xdata.dimension(function(d) {
  return d.district;
});
var groupByType = dimensionByType.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);


function reduceAdd(p, v) {
  p[v.type] = (p[v.type] || 0) + v.total;
  return p;
}

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
  p[v.type] = (p[v.type] || 0) - v.total;
  return p;
}

function reduceInitial() {
  return {};
}

var barChart = dc.barChart("#stackedBarChart")
  .width(1024)
  .height(200)
  .dimension(dimensionByType)
  .group(groupByType, "Type: 1", function(d) {
    return d.value[1] || 0;
  })
  .stack(groupByType, "Type: 2", function(d) {
    return d.value[2];
  })
  .stack(groupByType, "Type: 3", function(d) {
    return d.value[3];
  })
  .elasticX(true)
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
  .legend(dc.legend().x(500).y(1).itemHeight(15).gap(5));
barChart.yAxis().ticks(5);
barChart.xAxis().ticks(4);


dc.renderAll();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.9/dc.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.9/dc.min.css" />

<h1>StackedBart Chart:By Type and Quantity</h1>
<div id="stackedBarChart"></div>
<div id="stackedBarChart2"></div>
```

How I can make this work for my needs?

Comment: If you open browser console, there's an error `Uncaught Mandatory attribute chart.x is missing on chart[#stackedBarChart]` and it's not clear which property represents value (there's no property `total`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set x scale (even if you use `.elasticX(true)`) like this:

```
.x(d3.scale.ordinal())
```

Note also that in `.group` and `.stack` callbacks you have to use same names that in `reduceAdd` and `reduceRemove` is used (`type` property). 

Since your dataset lacked `total` property and anything value-like I've chosen to display `latitude` in following demo:

```js
var universe = [{
    "KMIST_TEMP_ID": "KTMPVN12119",
    "ID POP": "",
    "type": 2018,
    "pop": "No",
    "name": "Nha Thuoc An Binh",
    "Country": "",
    "Province": "Ho Chi Minh Province",
    "City": "Ho Chi Minh",
    "district": "Thu Duc",
    "ward": "Linh Trung",
    "name_full": "Ho Chi Minh ,Nha Thuoc An Binh ,Thu Duc, Linh Trung",
    "latitude": 10.8539167,
    "longitude": 106.7716921,
    "geo": "106.7716921,10.8539167",
    "amenity": "pharmacy",
    "date_entered": "2015-10-30T00:00:00",
    "date_issued": "2015-10-30T00:00:00"
  },

  {
    "KMIST_TEMP_ID": "KTMPVN12119",
    "ID POP": "",
    "type": 2018,
    "pop": "No",
    "name": "Nha Thuoc An Binh",
    "Country": "",
    "Province": "Ho Chi Minh Province",
    "City": "Ho Chi Minh",
    "district": "first",
    "ward": "Linh Trung",
    "name_full": "Ho Chi Minh ,Nha Thuoc An Binh ,Thu Duc, Linh Trung",
    "latitude": 10.8539167,
    "longitude": 106.7716921,
    "geo": "106.7716921,10.8539167",
    "amenity": "pharmacy",
    "date_entered": "2015-10-30T00:00:00",
    "date_issued": "2015-10-30T00:00:00"
  },

  {
    "KMIST_TEMP_ID": "KTMPVN12119",
    "ID POP": "",
    "type": "Never Covered",
    "pop": "No",
    "name": "Nha Thuoc An Binh",
    "Country": "",
    "Province": "Ho Chi Minh Province",
    "City": "Ho Chi Minh",
    "district": "new",
    "ward": "Linh Trung",
    "name_full": "Ho Chi Minh ,Nha Thuoc An Binh ,Thu Duc, Linh Trung",
    "latitude": 10.8539167,
    "longitude": 106.7716921,
    "geo": "106.7716921,10.8539167",
    "amenity": "pharmacy",
    "date_entered": "2015-10-30T00:00:00",
    "date_issued": "2015-10-30T00:00:00"
  },

  {
    "KMIST_TEMP_ID": "KTMPVN12119",
    "ID POP": "",
    "type": "Other Periods",
    "pop": "No",
    "name": "Nha Thuoc An Binh",
    "Country": "",
    "Province": "Ho Chi Minh Province",
    "City": "Ho Chi Minh",
    "district": "Thu Duc",
    "ward": "Linh Trung",
    "name_full": "Ho Chi Minh ,Nha Thuoc An Binh ,Thu Duc, Linh Trung",
    "latitude": 10.8539167,
    "longitude": 106.7716921,
    "geo": "106.7716921,10.8539167",
    "amenity": "pharmacy",
    "date_entered": "2015-10-30T00:00:00",
    "date_issued": "2015-10-30T00:00:00"
  }
];



var xdata = crossfilter(universe);
var dimensionByType = xdata.dimension(function(d) {
  return d.district;
});
var groupByType = dimensionByType.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);


function reduceAdd(p, v) {
  p[v.type] = (p[v.type] || 0) + v.latitude;
  return p;
}

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
  p[v.type] = (p[v.type] || 0) - v.latitude;
  return p;
}

function reduceInitial() {
  return {};
}

var barChart = dc.barChart("#stackedBarChart")
  .width(1024)
  .height(200)
  .dimension(dimensionByType)
  .group(groupByType, "Type: Never Covered", function(d) {
    return d.value['Never Covered'] || 0;
  })
  .stack(groupByType, "Type: 2018", function(d) {
    return d.value['2018'] || 0;
  })
  .stack(groupByType, "Type: Other Periods", function(d) {
    return d.value["Other Periods"] || 0;
  })
  .elasticY(true)
  .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
  .elasticX(true)
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
  .legend(dc.legend().x(500).y(1).itemHeight(15).gap(5));
barChart.yAxis().ticks(5);
barChart.xAxis().ticks(4);


dc.renderAll();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.9/dc.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.9/dc.min.css" />

<h1>StackedBart Chart:By Type and Quantity</h1>
<div id="stackedBarChart"></div>
<div id="stackedBarChart2"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help!